# How to share custom feed to facebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, html, share

I have a web page that has the user take a quiz, I would like them to then be able to share their results on facebook. I am using html, javascript, and jquery. I am wondering if there is a way to share custom feeds on facebook. Most people use php however I do not want to use php just keep it client side. I have been on facebook's documentation for a few days now and I can't seem to get a straight answer on how to add a button or link to my page that will share what I want it to share rather than the meta data of my site. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

The FB.ui feed dialog is perfect for that, JavaScript SDK only :)